# HBase write: which one better on performance, batch or put(List<Put>)?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, batch-processing

I am starting to learn HBase to write data streams. I use HTableInterface and having problem in performance. It took much times to insert only 500 rows, almost 500,000ms per batch List that I inserted.

Any example or suggestion for batch write into HTable with HTableInterface ?
I am using HBase 0.94

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're essentially the same: `batch(List<? extends Row> actions, Object[] results)` allows not only puts but also gets, deletes, increments... `put(List<Put> puts)` just do a batch of puts (it also validates them client-side).

You can also perform batches by disabling `table.setAutoFlush(false)`, issuing standard puts to the table and flushing the buffer afterwards with `table.flushCommits()`.

I don't know the size of your rows but unless they're huge it seems you have some sort of problem with your configuration (network latency maybe?), even performing 500 puts row by row should be performed a lot faster.

Comment: any example in scala ? I got problem translating it from Java example. Which one you prefer, batch or put ?

Comment: Never used scala but take a look at [this example of adapting the JAVA code to SCALA](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/Scala). Since it's not common to mix puts with other type of operations I tend to use `put(List<Put> puts)` for batching puts, but I'd bet there's no difference in performance between them.

Comment: Your issue must related to anything else: configuration, network... anyway please notice that performance of standalone and pseudo-distributed versions will be a lot worse than with a proper Hadoop + HBase cluster.

Comment: okay thanks, I'd love to try put(List<Put>). Do you have any suggestion to read or learn for network configuration or regionserver/zookeeper issue ?