# HTable.batch(List) v/s HTable.put(List)

Tags: hbase

Using which of the following will give a better performance with respect to put. 
HTable.put(List) or HTable.batch(List).

For a smaller dataset I could not infer

Comment: possible duplicate of [HBase write: which one better on performance, batch or put(List<Put>)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28229038/hbase-write-which-one-better-on-performance-batch-or-putlistput)

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference. Take a look at this answer which also shows an alternative way of doing it:

[HBase write: which one better on performance, batch or put(List<Put>)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28229038/hbase-write-which-one-better-on-performance-batch-or-putlistput/28230160#28230160)